# Rails 5: validate HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

How is it possible to validate an HBTM association ?
For example you have the following 2 models with HABTM relation:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages

  validates :code, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :countries
  validates :tag, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

How to validate a language before adding it to country languages ?
I have an idea to do smth like this:

```
  def check_for_existing_language(language)
    languages.include?(language) == true
  end
```

But where to put this callback method ? In `before_save` of `Country` model ?

Comment: Yea I would put it in `Country` model, under `before_save` you can define your method `check_for_existing_language`. It should get the job done.

Comment: I think a wiser way would be to use `before_add` callback as explained in [Rails Guides HABTM reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference).

Comment: Yup, you are correct. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521773/4160532) answer. It helped me understand also.

Comment: But, `before_add` does not seem to validate it and the same language is added to the country without any errors, I tried to play around with it in Rails console: `country = Country.create(code: 'fr')`; `language = Language.create(tag: 'fr-FR')`; `country.languages << language`;. This evaluated the callback to false. When re-assigning the same language: `country.languages << language`, it was added: `country.languages.size`=> `2`.

Comment: More of that, I can't see how to pass in a language instance to the callback method. I thing that's the problem.

Comment: How about you add it as `before_save` in `Language` model ? Since, you're verifying if the **language** exists

Comment: I'm not saving the `Language` model when calling `country.languages << language`, so there is no sense in doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180946/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-belgoros).

Comment: The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224837/has-and-belongs-to-many-find-if-exists/21224867#21224867) provided by @KedarnagMukanahallipatna let me figure out and make it work. Thank you.